# ASP.NET MVC Razor Chart within View rendered with Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

This seems like something so easy, and i am sure it is, but i cant figure out how to do it.

On my view i want a table and a chart, both sourced from the model.

The only options i have found is to create the chart inline (which then is the only thing displayed), use inside an img, or an Action or trying to write the bytes direct as a stream, all of which doesn't seem to support passing a model object.

How can i insert a chart in a view using the views model object so it coexists, either coding directly into the View or via some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way to do it from the view using

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart;
/* populate chart from Model here */
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(Html.ViewContext.Writer);
chart.RenderControl(writer);
```

Comment: Cool. I shall try this.